# Auto tester/debugger for g++?

Tags: c++, gdb, segmentation-fault

I just finished a project for my cryptography class and it all seems to go well (mostly). Because the key is generated randomly, I wanted to ensure it would work for all keys. Anyway, I ran it a bunch of times and hit a segfault at around the 30th run. I haven't been able to reproduce this segfault in gdb. Does gdb have a command, or is there some other method to continue running the program and then break when it segfaults so I can check the stack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place the loop inside your program so you only have to run it in the debugger once.

Comment: Haha, this just occurred to me. Oops.